# Ionic 3. How to target certain version of iOS emulator with cli?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I accidentally found out that my app crashes instantly while loaded on iOS 8.4

Doesn't work for me in latest Ionic version.
First I listed all of the available devices with

`ionic cordova emulate ios --list`

All of the available devices was listed. Something like:

```
iPhone-5s, 10.3
iPhone-5s, 10.2
iPhone-5s, 8.4
iPhone-6, 8.4
iPhone-6, 10.3
iPhone-6-Plus, 10.3
iPhone-6s, 10.3
iPhone-6s, 10.2
iPhone-7, 10.3
iPhone-7, 10.2
iPhone-7-Plus, 10.3
iPhone-7-Plus, 10.2
iPhone-SE, 10.3
iPhone-SE, 10.2
```

Next I picked one from the list and tried

`ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6, 10.3"`

but the build crashed with error.... I believe because of the incorrect parameter signature "iPhone-6, 10.3"

But `ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6"` works and pops up emulator with **iOS 8.4**
How to start the emulator with certain version of `iOS`?

Comment: I use this command and works ok: `ionic run ios --target="iPhone-6s, 10.3" --livereload`. Maybe the error is in that particular iOS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Open `run.js` file from:  `your_project_direcotry/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js` and search for valid target:

// validate target device for ios-sim

```
var validTargets = ['iPhone-5', 'iPhone-5s', 'iPhone-6-Plus', 'iPhone-6', 'iPhone-7', 'iPhone-SE', 'iPad-2', 'iPad-Retina', 'iPad-Air', 'Resizable-iPhone', 'Resizable-iPad'];
```

// Add your target here **iPhone-6-Plus, 10.3**

```
var validTargets = ['iPhone-5', 'iPhone-5s', 'iPhone-6-Plus', 'iPhone-6-Plus, 10.3', iPhone-6', 'iPhone-7', 'iPhone-SE', 'iPad-2', 'iPad-Retina', 'iPad-Air', 'Resizable-iPhone', 'Resizable-iPad'];
```